# Как связать свойства в 2х класcах, чтобы вывести нужное имя через GroupJoin

Tags: c#, linq

Даны два класса:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int OfficeId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Office
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ManagerId { get; set; }
    }
```

Дается группа строк с данными работников, и группа строк с данными офисов. Группы разделены между собой пустой строкой.

Для каждого работника вывести на экран имя работника, номер(id) офиса, и имя менеджера для этого работника. Если работник сам — менеджер, то в имя менеджера поставить прочерк. Работников отсортировать по их имени.

```
Sample Input 1:

1, Иванов Иван, 1
2, Алексеев Алексей, 2
3, Петров Пётр, 1
4, Сергеев Сергей, 1
5, Олегин Олег, 2
6, Людмилова Людмила, 1
7, Кириллов Кирилл, 2
8, Катеринина Екатерина, 1
9, Евгеньев Евгений, 2
10, Анастасьева Анастасия, 2
11, Афанасьев Афанасий, 1

1, 6
2, 7

Конец ввода

Sample Output 1:

Имя:Алексеев Алексей, Номер офиса:2, Имя начальника:Кириллов Кирилл
Имя:Анастасьева Анастасия, Номер офиса:2, Имя начальника:Кириллов Кирилл
Имя:Афанасьев Афанасий, Номер офиса:1, Имя начальника:Людмилова Людмила
Имя:Евгеньев Евгений, Номер офиса:2, Имя начальника:Кириллов Кирилл
Имя:Иванов Иван, Номер офиса:1, Имя начальника:Людмилова Людмила
Имя:Катеринина Екатерина, Номер офиса:1, Имя начальника:Людмилова Людмила
Имя:Кириллов Кирилл, Номер офиса:2, Имя начальника:-
Имя:Людмилова Людмила, Номер офиса:1, Имя начальника:-
Имя:Олегин Олег, Номер офиса:2, Имя начальника:Кириллов Кирилл
Имя:Петров Пётр, Номер офиса:1, Имя начальника:Людмилова Людмила
Имя:Сергеев Сергей, Номер офиса:1, Имя начальника:Людмилова Людмила
```

У меня получается вывести все, кроме имя менеджера, не понимаю как по свойству OfficeId из 1 класса вывести имя менеджера через класс Office по свойству ManagerId

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int OfficeId { get; set; }
    public Employee(int id, string name, int officeid) 
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        OfficeId = officeid;
    }
}

public class Office
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
    public Office(int id, int managerId)
    {
        Id = id;
        ManagerId = managerId;
    }
}

public class Program 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {

        // Данные О Работниках 

        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        var listEmployes = new List<Employee>();
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) 
        {
            var SplitLine = line.Split(", ");
            listEmployes.Add(new Employee(int.Parse(SplitLine[0]), SplitLine[1], int.Parse(SplitLine[2])));
            line = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // Данные Оффиса

        var listOffice = new List<Office>();
        line = Console.ReadLine();
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        {
            var SplitLine = line.Split(", ");
            listOffice.Add(new Office(int.Parse(SplitLine[0]), int.Parse(SplitLine[1])));
            line = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        var SortedListEmployees = listEmployes.GroupJoin(listOffice, x => x.OfficeId, y => y.Id, (item, y) => new { id = item.Id, Name = item.Name, Officeid = item.OfficeId, Manager = y }); 
        foreach(var p in SortedListEmployees) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Имя:{p.Name}, Номер офиса:{p.Officeid} ");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопрос решён? Если нет, редактируйте вопрос, чтобы он снова всплыл на главной странице сайта - его увидят (и, возможно, помогут). Если да, можно самостоятельно опубликовать ответ.

Comment: Отредактировал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные:

```
var employes = new List<Employee>
{
    new Employee { Id = 1,  Name = "Иванов Иван",           OfficeId = 1 },
    new Employee { Id = 2,  Name = "Алексеев Алексей",      OfficeId = 2 },
    new Employee { Id = 3,  Name = "Петров Пётр",           OfficeId = 1 },
    new Employee { Id = 4,  Name = "Сергеев Сергей",        OfficeId = 1 },
    new Employee { Id = 5,  Name = "Олегин Олег",           OfficeId = 2 },
    new Employee { Id = 6,  Name = "Людмилова Людмила",     OfficeId = 1 },
    new Employee { Id = 7,  Name = "Кириллов Кирилл",       OfficeId = 2 },
    new Employee { Id = 8,  Name = "Катеринина Екатерина",  OfficeId = 1 },
    new Employee { Id = 9,  Name = "Евгеньев Евгений",      OfficeId = 2 },
    new Employee { Id = 10, Name = "Анастасьева Анастасия", OfficeId = 2 },
    new Employee { Id = 11, Name = "Афанасьев Афанасий",    OfficeId = 1 }
};

var offices = new List<Office>
{
    new Office { Id = 1, ManagerId = 6 },
    new Office { Id = 2, ManagerId = 7 }
};
```

Я не вижу смысла в применении `GroupJoin`. Получаем сгруппированные офисы, а что это нам даёт? Ничего.

Достаточно простого `Join`.
Решение:

```
var result = employes.Join(
    offices,
    employee => employee.OfficeId,
    office => office.Id,
    (employee, office) => new
    {
        OfficeId = office.Id,
        EmployeeName = employee.Name,
        ManagerName = employes.First(x => x.Id == office.ManagerId).Name
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.EmployeeName);

foreach (var x in result)
    Console.WriteLine($"{x.OfficeId}  {x.EmployeeName,-23} {x.ManagerName}");
```

Чтобы получить имя менеджера, приходится внутри `Join` осуществлять вложенный поиск с помощью метода `First`. Это приводит к квадратичной сложности, что очень неэффективно на больших объёмах данных.
Можно ввести дополнительный словарь. Поиск по нему намного эффективней. Но тратится лишняя память на сам словарь.

```
var dict = employes.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.Name);

var result = employes.Join(
    offices,
    employee => employee.OfficeId,
    office => office.Id,
    (employee, office) => new
    {
        OfficeId = office.Id,
        EmployeeName = employee.Name,
        ManagerName = dict[office.ManagerId]
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.EmployeeName);
```

Сортировка делается с помощью `OrderBy`.

Вообще, не обязательно данные изначально помещать в списки `List`. Иногда есть смысл сразу помещать их в словари, хешсеты и другие структуры данных.